# Carbon auto increments time by 11 minutes on parse

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, timezone, php-carbon, timezone-offset

I am using Carbon with Laraveal, my local timezone is in IST. I am passing the below ISO string from the UI.

```
2019-11-22T03:00:00.000Z
```

When parsed on the server with the below syntax:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->timezone($this->user->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

The output I am getting is :

```
2019-11-22 03:11:00
```

Don't know why I am getting the additional 11 minutes in the time. UI and Server both runs in my local machine. Don't know what's causing the 11 minutes addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');`

should be

`->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Notice the `m` for months and `i` for minutes.

[See PHP docs for formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)